# Go math operations with different results

Tags: go

(I hope) this is not a question about the accuracy of floating point math in Go. Below I have a test function with 2 expressions that I think should produce equal results, but given the inputs, produce different output.

**Edit** This ended up being just about floating point precision.

[Playground Source](http://play.golang.org/p/brlPIgL2Un)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test(10.0, 0.1, 1.0)) // 0.2
    fmt.Println(test(10.0, 0.2, 1.0)) // 0.3
    fmt.Println(test(10.0, 0.3, 1.0)) // 0.4
    fmt.Println(test(10.0, 0.4, 1.0)) // 0.5
    fmt.Println(test(10.0, 0.5, 1.0)) // 0.6
}

func test(plays float64, rate float64, value float64) float64 {
    // return (value/plays) + rate
    return (plays*rate + value) / plays
}
```

The first expression `(value/plays) + rate` prints:

```
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
```

while the second expression `(plays*rate + value) / plays` prints the expected output:

```
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
```

Why is this?

Comment: I'm afraid it is about the accuracy of floating-point operations. :) Another multiply and divide can change the result a just skooch, which seems consistent with that output. You could try the same thing in a toy C program to check--write `test1` and `test2` and see if `test1(10.0, 0.2, 1.0) == test2(10.0, 0.2, 1.0)`.

Comment: Your basically calculating: `float64(0.2) + float64(0.1)` which is definitely `0.30000000000000004`

Comment: You might want to google "what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic".

Comment: I actually like the solution of using `fmt.Printf("%.1f", test(...))` best. [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/PEcr4S_Ur4). I think it's correct to specify the output precision.

Comment: Note that there is a `Rat` rational number type in the `"big"` library, so if you need exact results, you can use that type.  https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Rat

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/CFgK9aYibA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since floating point arithmetic is involved, the results for the two expressions will not be the same, even when the input is the same. They may *appear* to be the same once rounded off to a smaller number of precision positions.

The reason one of the outputs shows 17 digits after the decimal, while the remaining show only 1, is probably because you are hitting a boundary condition with the 3.0000.... result for the way Println rounds off the floating point values while formating output. To demonstrate the boundary condition, consider the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000000)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000001)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000002)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000003)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000004)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000005)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000006)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000007)
    fmt.Println(0.30000000000000008)
}
```

The output is:

```
0.3
0.3
0.30000000000000004
0.30000000000000004
0.30000000000000004
0.30000000000000004
0.30000000000000004
0.30000000000000004
0.3000000000000001
```

The results of the first two values are truncated and hence the output shows precision of 1 while the other values are rounded off but the precision is much greater. I did not look into the source code of fmt package but this seems to be a result of the way Println truncates floating point values.

Changing the playground code in the question above to use Printf with a large value for precision gives an idea about what the results actually look like. Here's the modified code in the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/wONNsuATkx)

Comment: Using Printf and specifying precisions was very insightful.